# Material UI Palette not updating

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and Material UI, i'm trying to add some custom styles to the MUI buttons by using the createMuiTheme.

I've followed the docs and pretty much copied the example but it's having no effect and no errors are being thrown in the console.

I've been banging my head against this for a while now and I can't see what the problem is, what am I missing?

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const mytheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: { main: '#1565C0'},
        secondary: { main: '#11cb5f' }, 
    },
});

export const PrimaryButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={mytheme}>
            <a href={props.buttonLink}>
                <Button
                    style={{ ...props.styles}}
                    onClick={props.handleClick}
                    variant='contained' color='primary' size='large'
                >
                    {props.buttonText}
                </Button>
            </a>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export const SecondaryButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={mytheme}>
            <Button
                style={{...props.styles }}
                value={props.value || ''}
                onClick={props.handleClick}
                variant='outlined' color='secondary' size='large'
            >
                {props.buttonText}
            </Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: It works fine, I tried it https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wu-b8kqg. I changed the primary color and it works

Comment: Hey, thanks for setting that up. I can see it's working there. The problem is the default styles are still being applied and are applied after my custom styles so are over writing them, which I'm not sure why that is happening..

Comment: Do you have any warnings in the console about multiple instances of `@material-ui/styles`?

Comment: No console warnings, the below answer has fixed it, I needed to wrap the whole App in the ThemeProvider and style globally rather than per component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working. Try to change this:

```
variant='outlined'
```

by

```
variant='contained'
```

Comment: That prop is present on the PrimaryButton. I just checked and the styles are being provided, however they are being over written but the MUI styles.

Comment: So i am not following what you need actually. Do you want to change the value in the whole application? Or just in the component?

Comment: So when I check the dev tools, I can see that my styles are being applied to > MuiButton-containedPrimary. However higher up in the hierarchy the default MUI settings are being applied and over riding my styles. I guess I need to apply them for the whole application to fix this?

Comment: Yes. Check out this codesandbox and let me know if it helps you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-galois-lcryu

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to choose your answer ... otherwise people will try to answer you.